# Zend Framework 2 Twig Translate

Tags: zend-framework2, twig, translate, po

I'm using Zend Framework 2.3.1 with Twig as my template engine and ZfTwig extension.

I want to use the Twig translate syntax but with the Zend translator, so PoEdit can parse it.

Is there a (simple) way to realize my ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you use Twig as a template engine you'll handle `.twig` files and not `.phtml` files. Twig files have different syntax from PHP files, and by default Poedit does not have the ability to parse twig templates.

However, you can add a new extractor to Poedit which will allow you to parse Twig templates just like you do with plain PHP templates. You can use [Twig-Gettext-Extractor](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor). It can be easily installed through composer. Once you install all dependencies you can configure Poedit by adding new Twig parser.

This is the parser command :

```
<project>/vendor/bin/twig-gettext-extractor --sort-output --force-po -o %o %C %K -L PHP --files %F
```

In Poedit, Edit > Preferences > Parsers, enter the following options :

[image]

Or you may prefer to use it in command line like this :

```
./twig-gettext-extractor --sort-output --force-po -o messages.po -L PHP --files file1.twig file2.twig fileN.twig
```

Now your parser is configured and Poedit can scan the twig templates.

For more details about the installation and the configuration of Twig Gettext Extractor, you may refer to [README](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor/blob/master/README.md) file on Github.

Hope this helps.